# Cancelling an answer up-vote

Tags: support

I recently up-voted an answer but upon further reflection while not a really bad answer it didn't address a few aspects of the question. When I pressed down-vote it went from +1 to -1 instead of going back to zero.

I didn't think the answer deserved -1 so up-voted again to +1 but wondered if there is a way to just undo a vote so it would have gone back to zero in the above case? Not sure if I've missed something or if anyone else thinks it may be worthwhile feauture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just re-click the upvote mark to undo your vote. However, after a certain time (how long, I do not know) your vote is "locked": you cannot undo it (or change it into a downvote) until the answer is edited.

Comment: Ahh thanks Camil, seems a bit counter-intuitive but just tried on your answer just now and see how it works.

Comment: For *all* those meta points :)